# Speed up UniVerse access times using UniObjects

Tags: c#, .net, universe, uniobjects

I am accessing a UniVerse database and reading out all the records in it for the purpose of synchronizing it to a MySQL database which is used for compatibility with some other applications which use the data. Some of the tables are >250,000 records long with >100 columns and the server is rather old and still used by many simultaneous users and so it takes a very ... long ... time to read the records sometimes.

Example: I execute SSELECT <file> TO 0 and begin reading through the select list, parsing each record into our data abstraction type and putting it in a .NET List. Depending on the moment, fetching each record can take between 250ms to 3/4 second depending on database usage. Removing the methods for extraction only speeds it up marginally since I think it still downloads all of the record information anyway when I call UniFile.read even if I don't use it.

Reading 250,000 records at this speed is prohibitively slow, so does anyone know a way I can speed this up? Is there some option I should be setting somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to use SSELECT (sorted select)? The sorting on record key will create an additional performance overhead. If you do not need to synchronise in a sorted manner just use a plain SELECT and this should improve the performance.

If this doesn't help then try to automate the synchronisation to run at a time of low system usage, when either few or no users are logged onto the UniVerse system, if at all possible.

Other than that it could be that some of the tables you are exporting are in need of a resize. If they are not dynamic files (automatic-resizing - type 30), they may have gone into overflow space on disk.
To find out the size of your biggest tables and to see if they have gone into overflow you can use commands such as FILE.STAT and HASH.HELP at the command line to retrieve more information. Use HELP FILE.STAT or HELP HASH.HELP to look at the documentation for these commands, in order to extract the information that you need.

If these commands show that your files are of type 30, then they are automatically resized by the database engine. If however the file types are anything from type 2 to 18 the HASH.HELP command may recommend changes you can make to the table size to increase it's performance.

If none of this helps then you could check for useful indexes on the tables using LIST.INDEX TABLENAME ALL, which you could maybe use to speed up the selection.

Comment: It turns out the way I was accessing the server (an ssh tunnel to get through a firewall) was actually the bottleneck. So, we are going to have the service run inside the firewall to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your files are sized correctly using ANALYZE-FILE fileName. If not dynamic ensure there is not too much overflow.

Using SELECT instead of SSELECT will mean you are reading data from the database sequentially rather than randomly and be signicantly faster.

You should also investigate how you are extracting the data from each record and putting it into a list. Usually the pick data separators chars 254, 253 and 252 will not be compatible with the external database and need to be converted. How this is done can make an enormous difference to the performance.

It is not clear from the initial post, however a WRITESEQ would probably be the most efficient way to output the file data.